# amēn vs. Verily/Truly

Tags: greek, new-testament

In the Greek text for Matthew 5:18, the word “amēn” is used at the beginning of the sentence. From my understanding, this was used to express that the following statement was true or held in high regard. The same word, “amēn,” was used to end a prayer. In most English translations, amēn is translated to “truly” or “verily.” Is there a reason why it could not be left at the English “amen?” If amen in English means “so be it,” then why can’t it be used before the sentence in the same way it was in the Greek?

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Glad you are here.  Please remember to take the site tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.

Answer (score 2):

According to BDAG, the word ἀμήν is transliterated from the Hebrew and has two basic meanings:

1. **strong affirmation of what is being said**

- (a) **as expression of faith**, *let it be so, truly, amen*, eg, 1 Cor 4:16, Rev 5:14, Matt 5:13, Rom 1:25, 9:5, 11:36, etc
- (b) assertive particle, ***truly***, always with λέγω beginning a solemn declaration; but only used by Jesus (I assure you that, I solemnly tell you) Matt 5:18, 26, 6:2, 5, 16, 8:10, Mark 3:28, etc.

2. **Christ as the ultimate affirmation, *the Amen***, eg, Rev 3:14.

Thus, Matt 5:18 is as listed above - a solemn declaration; but only used by Jesus (I assure you that, I solemnly tell you).

The practice ending a prayer with "amen" dates at least from NT times.

Comment: Ah, thanks! So it wouldn’t be incorrect for it to be translated as “Amen, I tell you…?”

Comment: But it wouldn’t follow guidelines?

Comment: @awholegnuworld - we must distinguish between a title of Jesus and the assertive particle. In the presence of the verb "lego" (Isay) it is always the latter.

Comment: Ah, I get it. Thanks!